# Are the traditional Fletcher/Adler checksum algorithms optimal?

Tags: algorithm

Are the traditional Fletcher/Adler checksum algorithms optimal?

I am not referring to the common optimizations applied to these
algorithms. For example, the controlling of loop iterations to
avoid sum overflows then truncating outside of the main loop.

I am referring to the design itself. I understand the second sum
(sum2) was introduced to make the algorithm position-dependent but
it is truly sub-optimal? Sum2 is just a modification of sum1 (the
sum of the previous sum1 value added to the current sum1 value).

If we take the 16-bit version as our example, sum1 is a 8-bit
product of the input data, while sum2 is a product of sum1, so
therefore the final 16-bit checksum is in fact an 8-bit product
of the data appended to 16-bits to catch out-of-sequence input.

This means our final checksum, an 8-bit sum of our input data,
is a value of only 256 possible values. As we are passing on
a 16-bit value with our data we could have a checksum value that
is one of 65536 possible values.

It occurred to me that if we had a means of ensuring a position-
dependent check without sacrificing any bits of the checksum we
would have an exponentially better validation.

As I understand it, sum2 was introduced solely to identify out-
of-sequence transmission, and so can be discarded if we find an
alternative to producing a position-dependent checksum. And as
it turns out, we do have an alternative and it comes cheap.

It is cheap because it does not add extra coding to the process
compared to current 'sum2' designs - it is the index position
in the sequence that when hashed with each corresponding byte
ensures a position-dependent check.

One final note - the design below is free of overflow checks,
lossless reduction, and possible loop optimizations, just for
clarity, as this is
about a new out-of-sequence error check technique, not about
implementation details. Fletch64 is not demonstrated below as
it may require a more complicated implementation but the
byte/index hash applies the same.

Revision - because a checksum algorithm can process a large data
count the index position check value could itself cause premature
overflow and require a higher number of reduction operations with
lower inner loop count. The fix was to truncate the index position
check to 8 bits. Now the checksum can process a much greater data
count in the inner loop before overflow.

The only down-side to this change is if a contiguous string of the
data of exactly 256 byte is displaced any multiple of 256 positions
from its original position the error would go undetected.

```
uint8_t Fletch8( uint8_t *data, int count )
 {
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  int index;

  for ( index = 0; index < count; ++index )
    sum = sum + ( data[index] xor index & ffh );

  return sum & ffh;
 }

uint16_t Fletch16( uint8_t *data, int count )
 {
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  int index;

  for ( index = 0; index < count; ++index )
    sum = sum + ( data[index] xor index & ffh );

  return sum & ffffh;
 }

uint32_t Fletch32( uint8_t *data, int count )
 {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  int index;

  for ( index = 0; index < count; ++index )
    sum = sum + ( data[index] xor index & ffh );

  return sum & ffffffffh;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. I suggest changing the function names to something innocuous *not* suggesting an intimate relation to [Fletcher's checksum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher's_checksum#Comparison_with_the_Adler_checksum).

Comment: (Your proposal suffers from the same shortcoming as Adler's: it takes a significant message length to influence the highest bits.)

Comment: (Regarding the suitability of the XOR of a range of binary coded integers, search for a computation thereof - a somewhat popular topic with SO (StackOverflow).)

Comment: You really need to define your notion of optimality, so we can decide whether or not we care about that metric, and whether or not you achieve it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help

Comment: BTW, the paper ["The Effectiveness of Checksums for Embedded Control Networks" (Maxino, Koopman)](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/pubs/maxino09_checksums.pdf) linked to off that Wikipedia page on the Fletcher checksum is quite interesting. The conclusions are actually a "cookbook" for selecting the right checksum given various conditions.

Comment: (`[Fletch<nBits>() was a nod to its [inspirator]` How about `FitzFletcher<nBits>()` - ["illegitimate" descendant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitz#Revival).)

Comment: `Sum2 is just a modified copy of sum1 (the sum of the previous sum1 value added to the current sum1 value` Either you inspected a broken stab at implementing Fletcher's checksum, or you mistook `sum1` for `sum2`: [`sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % 255`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher's_checksum#Straightforward)

Comment: I appreciate the fact that the higher bits are rarely utilised,
however it is very different from Adlers I believe. The name was
a nod to its inspiration, it is a Fletcher spin-off and I wouldn't
know what else to call it :)

Comment: I am open to being corrected but I feel the XOR in this context is
ideal (the byte and its index produce a specific check value) which
is handled normally just like any other summing algorithm, it is
not related to the unsuitability of use with encoding you refer to,
as far as I can tell. Cheers

Comment: By optimal I mean a greater checksum bit-count with less information
loss - a narrow bit-count even with overflow feedback will incur a
greater chance of collisions (errors producing the same checksum)

Comment: Thanks david - this design would suit any condition where a checksum
algorithm is appropriate. greybeard - Sum2 is just an accumulator
summing all iteration states of sum1. It is not a unique product of
the data but a product of sum1.

Comment: I still contend the traditional simple checksum algorithms by Fletcher
are sub-optimal - they accumulate information about the data in only
half the bits, even with lossless reduction, it cannot retain
information beyond the available bits capacity, which is half what
it could be.

Comment: So my research into the links you provided me have enlightened me
to the great amount of effort done analysing and optimizing these
data checking algorithms. I still insist that such effort combined
with new more efficient position-dependence check would yield the
8-bit to be as effective as the current 16, and the 16-bit to be as
effective as the 32, etc. Happy coding :)

Comment: BTW greybeard - I like your reference to Fitz :) How about Fitzler ?

Comment: It was the cable guy! Fletcher was at work busy creating his brilliant algorithm. Even if errors cause the low half bits to cycle around to the same value, the top half (sum2) would also be affected by the errors and in fact amplify them. Of course all bits identify errors, and more effectively! Mine is just a plain summing technique and even with position-dependence is not as effective as a Fletcher at the same bit-count, let alone what I was claiming. Sorry for my ignorance and thanks all. I think his name was Fizzer, or Fizog, and he got the sack for taking too long to make the connection.